# Программа не проходит тесты, нужна помощь в оптимизации программы

Tags: c

*Задание выглядит так:*

В стандартный поток ввода поступает выражение вида: _ _ *.*_ * _ *.* _ _ _ _ _ , где «_» – цифра, а «*» - знак умножения. Числа, подаваемые на вход, записываются без пробелов. На вход подаются только числа, точки и знак умножения, причем заведомо некорректный ввод невозможен. Для выполнения данного задания нельзя использовать вещественные типы данных. Лишние нули в дроби не выводить. Вывести ответ в стандартный поток вывода.

*Вот мой код:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void delZero(char* result) {
  int i = 0;
  while (result[i] == '0' && i < strlen(result) - 1) i++;
  if (i > 0) memmove(result, result + i, strlen(result) - i + 1);
}
int main(void) {
  char str[140];
  char str1[5];
  char str2[8];
  fgets(str, 13, stdin);

  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while (str[i] != '*') {
    str1[i] = str[i];
    i++;
  }
  str1[4] = '\0';
  str1[2] = str[3];
  str1[3] = str1[4];
  i++;

  j = i;
  i = 0;

  while (j != 12) {
    str2[i] = str[j];
    i++;
    j++;
  }

  str2[7] = '\0';

  str2[1] = str2[2];
  str2[2] = str2[3];
  str2[3] = str2[4];
  str2[4] = str2[5];
  str2[5] = str2[6];
  str2[6] = '\0';

  delZero(str1);

  int val_str1 = atoi(str1);
  int val_str2 = atoi(str2);
  int result;
  char res[15];
  char mant[15];
  char res_part[15];
  int mant_part = 0;


  result = val_str1 * val_str2;
  switch (result) {
  case 0: printf("%d", 0); break;
  default: sprintf(res, "%d", result);

    int len_of_res = strlen(res);
    for (i = len_of_res - 1; i > 2; i--) {
      res[i] = '\0';
    }
    mant_part = result % 1000000;
    sprintf(mant, "%d", mant_part);
    int len_of_mant = strlen(mant);
    for (int i = strlen(mant) - 1; (i >= 0) && (mant[i] == '0'); i--) {
      mant[i] = '\0';
    }
    int int_part = result - mant_part;
    sprintf(res_part, "%d", int_part);
    int len_of_res_part = strlen(res_part);

    for (i = (len_of_res_part)-1, j = 0; j != 6; i--) {
      res_part[i] = '\0';
      j++;
    }

    printf("%s.%s", res_part, mant); break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

*Тесты, которые не проходят:*

```
Ввод: 00.1*0.00001
Вывод: 0.000001
Ввод: 14.0*9.00000
Вывод: 126
```

Comment: И как 00.1 или 14.0 соответствуют шаблону  `_ . `,  *где «_» – цифра*?

Comment: @Harry извиняюсь, не увидел, что форматирование неправильное
исправил.

Comment: Я бы просто читал в целые числа 3 цифры до умножения и 6 после, игнорируя точки, перемножал, выводил с учетом того, что 6 цифр получившегося результата — десятичная дробь...

Answer (score 1):

Какое-то у вас решение из серии *Зачем просто, если можно сложно?* :) Раз уж *заведомо некорректный ввод невозможен*, то все проверки убираем, и, как я писал в комментарии —

> Я бы просто читал в целые числа 3 цифры до умножения и 6 после, игнорируя точки, перемножал, выводил с учетом того, что 6 цифр получившегося результата — десятичная дробь...

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, p = 1000000;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        int c = getc(stdin);
        if (c == '.') c = getc(stdin);
        a = a*10 + c - '0';
    }
    getc(stdin); // *
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        int c = getc(stdin);
        if (c == '.') c = getc(stdin);
        b = b*10 + c - '0';
    }
    a *= b;
    printf("%d.",a/p);
    a %= p;
    while(a)
    {
        p /= 10;
        printf("%d",a/p);
        a %= p;
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Единственная проблема в том, что например тип double поддерживает числа длиной в 308 знаков, float в 38, а данная программа только около 19...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef unsigned char len_t;
typedef unsigned long long long_t;

struct Number {
    len_t k;
    long_t a;
    long_t b;
    long_t mul;
};

bool isNumber(char c) { return c >= '0' && c <= '9'; }

len_t len(long_t val) {
    len_t res = 1;
    for(; val > 9; ++res, val /= 10);
    return res;
}

void print(struct Number num) {
    printf("%d", num.a);

    if(!num.b) { return; }

    printf(".");
    for(len_t i = len(num.b); i < num.k; ++i)
        printf("0");
    printf("%d", num.b);
}

void scan(struct Number* num) {
    char c;

    num->a = 0;
    num->b = 0;
    num->k = 0;
    num->mul = 1;

    /* Целая часть числа */

    // Пропускаем нули
    scanf("%c", &c);
    while(c == '0') { scanf(" %c", &c); }

    // Сканируем целую часть числа в num.a
    while(c != '.') {
        num->a *= 10;
        num->a += c - '0';
        scanf(" %c", &c);
    }

    /* Действительная часть числа */

    len_t lenght = 0;

    // Пропускаем нули
    scanf(" %c", &c);
    while(c == '0') {
        ++lenght;
        num->mul *= 10;
        scanf("%c", &c);
    }

    // Если действительная часть содержит только нули,
    // выходим из функции
    if(!isNumber(c)) { num->mul = 1; return; }

    // Добавляем кол-во предшествующих нулей к num.k
    num->k += lenght;
    lenght = 0;

    // Сканируем целую часть числа в num.b
    // И кол-во знаков после запятой в num.k
    while(isNumber(c)) {
        if(c == '0') { ++lenght; }
        if(c != '0') {
            num->mul *= 10;
            num->k += lenght + 1;
            for(; lenght > 0; --lenght) {
                num->b *= 10;
                num->mul *= 10;
            }

            num->b *= 10;
            num->b += c - '0';
        }
        scanf("%c", &c);
    }
}

// Пусть num = a + q, где a - целая часть, q - действительная (0 < q < 1)
// Тогда num1 * num2 = (a1 + q1) * (a2 * q2) =
//       = a1 * a2 + a2 * q1 + a1 * q2 + q1 * q2
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Пусть q = b * 10^(-k), где b и k - целые числа
// Тогда q1 * q2 = b1 * b2 * 10^(-(k1+k2))
//       a2 * q1 = a2 * b1 * 10^(k2) * 10^(-(k1+k2))
//       a1 * q2 = a1 * b2 * 10^(k1) * 10^(-(k1+k2))
// Итого:
// a2 * q1 + a1 * q2 + q1 * q2 =
// = (b1 * b2 + a2 * b1 * 10^(k2) + a1 * b2 * 10^(k1)) * 10^(-(k1+k2))
void mult(struct Number num1, struct Number num2, struct Number* res) {
    // Задаём a = a1 * a2 и k = k1 + k2
    res->b = 0;
    res->a = num1.a * num2.a;
    res->k = num1.k + num2.k;
    res->mul = num1.mul * num2.mul;

    // res.b = b1 * b2 + a2 * b1 * 10^(k2) + a1 * b2 * 10^(k1)
    res->b += num1.b * num2.b;
    res->b += num2.a * num1.b * num2.mul;
    res->b += num1.a * num2.b * num1.mul;

    // Прибавляем к res.a целую часть остатка
    res->a += res->b / res->mul;

    // Отрезаем от остатка целую часть
    res->b %= res->mul;

    // Отрезаем последние нули
    while(res->k > 1 && !(res->b % 10)) {
        --res->k;
        res->b /= 10;
        res->mul /= 10;
    }
}

int main() {
    struct Number res, num1, num2;

    (void) scan(&num1);
    (void) scan(&num2);
    (void) mult(num1, num2, &res);
    (void) print(res);
    return 0;
}
```